# Matplotlib Python inline on/off

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

If I start an IPython Notebook with Matplotlib inlined, is there a way to subsequently plot a figure so that it shows in the “standard”, non-inlined, way, without having to reload the notebook without the inline command?

I'd like to be able to have some figures inlined in the notebook, but others in the traditional interactive mode, where I can zoom and pan.

Answer (score 58):

You can switch the matplotlib's backend by `%matplotlib <backend>`. To switch back to your system's default backend use `%matplotlib auto` or just simply `%matplotlib`.

There are many backends available such as `gtk`, `qt`, `notebook`, etc. I personally highly recommend the `notebook` (a.k.a. `nbagg`) backend. It is similar to `inline` but interactive, allowing zooming/panning from inside Jupyter.

For more info try: `?%matplotlib` inside an IPython/Jupyter or [IPython's online documentation](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)

Comment: typing `%matplotlib` kills the kernel for me, and I have to rerun the notebook from scratch after typing this command. Is there a way of doing this without killing the kernel?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue so I am not sure what is causing that for you. I tested with numpy 1.11.0, matplotlib 1.5.1 and IPython 5.0.0. I had some non-matplotlib-related kernel crashing problems with Numpy 1.11.1, and downgrading to 1.11.0 solved the issue for me.

Comment: For me worked only with ```auto```, simple ```%matplotlib``` throws an exeption

Answer (score 17):

`plt.ioff()` and `plt.ion()` works like a charm in my Jupyter notebook with the `notebook` as backend (assuming the usual `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`).

Comment: Despite calling `ion()` or `ioff()` the plot is always displayed inline for me.

Comment: ion and ioff set interactive mode, determining if the plot is updated after each plotting command (interactive mode on) or it waits plt.show() (if interactive mode is off).
This is independent on inline, that decides if the notebook or the console should display the graphics (this happens any time the plot is updated, meaning at every plotting command if interactive mode is set with ion, or after plt.plot if unset with ioff).

Answer (score 11):

It depends on the exact configuration of your matplotlib, 
but you can switch between inline and one of 'osx', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'gtk3', 'wx', 'qt', 'gtk', 'tk' (some are aliases of other). just use `%matplotlib <the one you want>` to switch. Depending on conditions you migh have only access to one of these.

Comment: If I switch to/from qt in the middle of a notebook, I often get plots that fail to load and cause the kernel to crash (usually the qt plots). This is on version 3.1.1.

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility is to use `matplotlib.pyplot.close(fig)`. This works for me even though `%matplotlib auto` raises a horrible `wx` error (related to the versions of the GTK development files I have installed in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

While this might cause problems if you're doing something like making a video (or it might not; haven't tried), it worked for me when assembling images in a table using `IPython.display.HTML` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741809/in-an-html-table-how-to-add-text-beside-plot-in-jupyter-notebook-using-python).

Comment: It didn't cause issues for me when creating an animation.