# How to DISABLE Jupyter notebook matplotlib plot inline?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter

Well, I know I can use `%matplotlib inline` to plot inline.

However, how to disable it?

Sometime I just want to zoom in the figure that I plotted. Which I can't do on a inline-figure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878666/matplotlib-python-inline-on-off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%matplotlib notebook` to change to a zoom-able display.

Comment: Sadly, this won't disable plot inline. But you provide a better solution. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

`%matplotlib auto` should switch to the default backend.

Answer (score 0):

I also like plots by matplotlib to be plotted in their own separate window so you can manipulate them via their controls.

However, I ran into issues with "blank plots" showing up or the plots "freezing" up, become unresponsive with the thinking icon.

When such happens, I always fix that, but not always in the same way. But any of the following 2 methods always helps me out:

**Method 1**
Start a cell like so:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
```

Then in the next cell type:

```
plt.hist([3,8,10])
```

In most cases the plot will appear in its own window.

**Method 2**
However, sometimes (not sure why), this does not work even after a kernel restart.

You may see a little window appear that does not show the plot but remains blank and if you hover over it with the mouse, you'll get the "thinking" icon.

In that case end your plotting cell like so:

```
plt.pause(1)
```

This should show the plots in the figures and they should be responsive too.

Good luck!

Tested on:

```
Windows 10
jupyter running inside Visual Studio Code 1.83.1
jupyter_client==8.6.0
jupyter_core==5.7.1
jupyterlab_widgets==3.0.10
python 3.10.13
matplotlib 3.8.2
```