# In an HTML table, how to add text beside plot in jupyter notebook using python?

Tags: html, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, bytesio

Any ideas on how to create a 1 X 2 HTML table where cell {0} is a matplotlib plot and cell {1} is a text description for Python 3.X?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO
%matplotlib inline

def add_split_screen(fig, text, iwidth=None):

    figdata = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(figdata, format='png') 
    figdata.seek(0)
    figdata
    figdata.close()
    iwidth = ' width={0} '.format(iwidth) if iwidth is not None else ''
    datatable = '<table><tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr></table>'.format(figdata, text)
    display(HTML(datatable))
```

Setting up a test case:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(6,4))
ax.plot([1,2,3])
text = '<h4>Special Chart:</h4><BR>Description of chart will go here.'
```

Then running the function in a Jupyter notebook:

```
add_split_screen(fig, text, iwidth='500px')
```

My output is as follows:
[image]

However, I am interested in actually seeing the plot inline a Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you've read the [document](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format_description.html#display-data) and are on the right track by using `BytesIO`. Two more steps to do are just:

1. Use a proper  tag for you plot
2. Encode your `figdata` using Base64. Then decode them into `str`

Here is a complete and verifiable (in Jupyter notebook) example modified from your code:

```
from base64 import b64encode
from io import BytesIO

from IPython.display import display, HTML
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def add_split_screen(fig, text, iwidth=None):
    figdata = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(figdata, format='png')
    iwidth = ' width={0} '.format(iwidth) if iwidth is not None else ''
    datatable = '<table><tr><td><img src="data:image/png;base64,{0}"/></td><td>{1}</td></tr></table>'.format(b64encode(figdata.getvalue()).decode(), text)
    display(HTML(datatable)) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(6,4))
ax.plot([1,2,3])
text = '<h4>Special Chart:</h4><BR>Description of chart will go here.'
add_split_screen(fig, text, iwidth='500px')
```

[image]