# prevent matplotlib output in jupyter notebook (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to render several hundred images with python and matplotlib using the following code:

```
def render_state(np_data_array):
    filename = "render/fig_" + str(i) + ".png"

    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,12) )
    aa = fig.add_subplot(111)
    aa.imshow(np_data_array,cmap='gray')

    fig.savefig(filename)
```

unfortunately matplotlib is also rendering everything into the jupyter notebook. 
Is there a way to prevent any output from matplotlib? I couldn't really find a way and most answers on the internet just say to not use plt.show() what I don't even use

Comment: If you don't have to render any plot at all in a notebook, don't call `%matplotlib inline`?

Comment: To prevent any output from a jupyter notebook cell, use `%%capture` as first line of the cell. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib python inline on/off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878666/matplotlib-python-inline-on-off)

Comment: %%capture works like charm! Thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 1):

`%%capture` as the first line of the cell works like charm!
Thanks to ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: It's always a good idea to allow time for the commenter, who provided you with solution, to post it as answer, and then you accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use `plt.close()` at the end of your notebook cell like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18718162/7613264). This way, you can still render other widgets like a `tqdm` progress bar. With `%%capture`, all widgets are blocked.