# How to suppress matplotlib inline for a single cell in Jupyter Notebooks/Lab?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, inline, jupyter

I was looking at [matplotlib python inline on/off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878666/matplotlib-python-inline-on-off) and this kind of solves the problem but when I do `plt.ion()` all of the Figures pop up (100s of figures).  I want to keep them suppressed in a single cell.  Is there a `with` loop I can use to turn off `%matplotlib inline` or is this impossible?

Comment: What exactly *is* the problem? Why would you use `plt.ion()` in a jupyter cell? To suppress any output from a jupyter cell use `%%capture` as the first line of that cell. Is that what you mean?

Comment: `%%capture` can suppress all output from a Jupyter cell? I didn't know that.  I will take another look at the magic lines.  Thank you.  That will be a good fix for what I'm looking for atm.  Ideally, I would only want to turn off the plotting because I usually write to stdout at certain checkpoints but I could do without that in the meantime.  Ideally I would want something like `with %matplotlib inline == False: [code]`.  However, I realize that I completely butchered the syntax for the `with` statement, the `magic`, and the use of a `boolean` but I'm not sure if there's something similar.

Comment: There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717877/prevent-plot-from-showing-in-jupyter-notebook) also, which shows possible solutions. But I have to admit that none except `%%capture` ever worked for me (hence my answer there).

Comment: I added [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49545730/4124317) to the linked question. Should we mark this as duplicate? Given that there is no such thing as `without inline do:`? Else you should probably clearly state in how far this question is different from the other one, explaining why none of the four solutions are not working for you.

Comment: Maybe this one should be flagged as duplicate if `%%capture` was the only approach that worked for you.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, as pointed out in the newly added answer, `%matplotlib agg` would work as well. Did you try that?

Comment: I had a similar issue (???), I made a context manager to disable plotting in IPython, maybe it helps? See my question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52115896/can-i-prevent-spyder-from-displaying-inline-images-temporarily/52116123#52116123

Answer (score 4):

Figures closed before the end of the cell will not be shown. Calling `plt.close("all")` at the end of the cell will close all figures and none will be displayed in the cell's output.