# Python: Generate pandas plot in function but do not show it

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot columns of a pandas dataframe by a calling a function. A data frame is passed to a function and manipulated. A plot and the manipulated data frame is returned:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def custom_plot(df):
    tmp = df.plot(kind = 'bar')
    plt.legend(title = "Test")
    return  [tmp,df]

df = pd.DataFrame( {'x' : [1,2,3]})
p,d = custom_plot(df)
```

Executing this code displays this plot although I do not want it to be displayed:

[image]

I want to plot the returned object `p` in the Jupyter notebook by calling something like `p.show()`. There are 2 problems:

1. The plot is always displayed  when `custom_plot()` is called although I do not want it to be plotted.
2. When I want to plot `p` by calling `p.show()` this does not work. I am told AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'show'

How can this behavior be achieved?

Comment: Why do you need the plot data, when you can call `df.plot()` wherever you need and get the plot? If you want to plot in a specific figure/subplot, that can be achieved using the `ax` argument in pandas' `plot`

Comment: I need this function because this plot is generated 20 times with different data frames. This minimal example does not represent the complexity of the problem at all.

Comment: The link you posted does not help. None of the suggestions there change the output.

Comment: @HOSS_JFL Oh sorry given a wrong link, I have deleted above comment as well. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878666/matplotlib-python-inline-on-off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this (partly) solves the issue:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def custom_plot(df):
    tmp = df.plot(kind = 'bar')
    plt.legend(title = 'Test')
    fig = tmp.get_figure()
    plt.close()
    return fig, df

df = pd.DataFrame( {'x' : [1, 2, 3]})

p, d = custom_plot(df)
```

Closing the figure prevents it from showing. You can use `p` without the `.show()` to display the figure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`plt.ioff()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def custom_plot(df):
    plt.ioff()
    df.plot(kind = 'bar')
    plt.legend(title = "Test")
    return  [plt,df]

df = pd.DataFrame( {'x' : [1,2,3]})
p,d = custom_plot(df)

p.show()
```

Output (There was no image after the first cell)

[image]

**EDIT**

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
def custom_plot(df):
    f1 = plt.figure()
    ax1 = f1.add_subplot(111)
    df.plot(kind = 'bar',ax=ax1)
    ax1.legend(title='TEST')
    plt.close()
    return  [f1,df]

df = pd.DataFrame( {'x' : [1,2,3]})
p,d = custom_plot(df)
```

Now you can call `p` as well instead of `p.show()`

Comment: Thank you, but in my case the plot is shown also when p.show() is not called. This is the case both in Jupyter and Spyder. I do not know why.

Comment: @HOSS_JFL Please check the updated answer, also you can try to restart the kernel