# jupyter notebook - matplotlib shows figure even without calling plt.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-widget

The following is a simplified example of my code. The idea behind this class is to show the figure only when the `show` method is executed.

```py
# my_module.py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self._fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

    def show(self):
        x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
        y = np.sin(x)
        self.ax.plot(x, y)
        self._fig.tight_layout()
        self._fig.show()
```

The code works as expected when it is executed from a Python shell or ipython. However, if I run this inside a Jypter Notebook:

```py
from my_module import Test
t = Test()
```

At this point, an empty figure is visualized on the screen. I don't want that! Now, I tried to insert `plt.close(self._fig)` inside `__init__`, but then when I run `t.show()` I get `UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.`

I also tried to load `%matplotlib widget` with the previous edit `plt.close(self._fig)`. The pictures is only shown when `show` is called, but it is just a picture with no interactive frame.

Another option would be to rewrite the class in such a way that the figure is created inside the `show` method. This is far from optimal as I would need to re-adjust my tests.

Are there any other ways to get it working correctly on all shells?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34605935/5012099

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prevent plot from showing in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717877/prevent-plot-from-showing-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: I've looked into the aforementioned questions/answers and I've tried to add `plt.ioff()`. Now, if `%matplotlib widget` is executed on a JN cell, then only one picture will be shown. If `%matplotlib widget` IS NOT executed, then no picture is shown on the output cell: the UserWarning I mentioned in the OP is raised. I've also noticed that by instantiating the figure inside `__init__`, my sphinx documentation randomly insert the same plot twice. I hate matplotlib :( I probably have to refactor the class and tests in order to instantiate the figure only when `show()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

In the original post I've done two mistakes.

First, the figure was instantiated into the `__init__` method, then the `show` method was called. In an interactive environment, once the figure is created it will be shown on the screen. We could turn off that behaviour with `plt.ioff()`, but then two things can happen:

1. If `%matplotlib widget` was executed, the figure will show up only once when calling `t.show()`.
2. Otherwise, no plot will be shown on the screen when calling `t.show()`.

Hence, `plt.ioff()` is not a valid solution. Instead, the figure must be instantiated when `t.show()` is executed.

The second mistake I did was to use `self._fig.show()`. Remember, in a interactive environment the figure is shown as soon as it is instantiated. Then, the previous command shows the figure a second time! Instead, I have to use `plt.show()`, which only display the figure once.

Here is the correct code example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        # init some attributes
        pass

    def show(self):
        self._fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self._fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
        y = np.sin(x)
        self.ax.plot(x, y)
        self._fig.tight_layout()
        plt.show()

t = Test()  # no figure is shown
t.show()    # figure is shown
```